# email and phone validation on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have the below form and I would like to show error message on the form. so the users cannot save with proper email and phone# format.

Here is my vf :

```
<apex:page controller="Survey" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form id="SurveyForm" >
        <apex:pageblock Title="Please fill the survey:">
           <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:inputText value="{!account}" label="Account Name"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!contactNameTitle}" label="Contact Name & Title"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!phone}" label="Phone #"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!fax}" label="Fax #"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!email}" label="Email"/>
            <apex:inputText value="{!website}" label="Website"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <p><apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" style="width:100px;"/></p>
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>

    </apex:form>
    <script src="/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $('surveyForm').validate({
                  rules: {
                       name: "required",
                       email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                       },
                       comment: "required"
                  }

             });
        });
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Why exactly does what you have so far not work? Can you please **[edit]** your post to be more clear about what is lacking in the current implementation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are calling validate function on page load. You need to call this function on click Save button.
 Put **name** attribute like below:

```
<apex:inputText value="{!phone}" label="Phone #" id="phone"/>
<apex:inputText value="{!email}" label="Email" id="email"/>

****Call validateform() on onclick event as below:****

<p><apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" style="width:100px;" onclick="validateform();"/></p>

**put Script like below:**
    <script>
    function validateForm() {
       var email = document.getElementById("{!$Component.SurveyForm.email}");
    var phoneno= document.getElementById("{!$Component.SurveyForm.phone}");
       if ( email == null || email == "" ) {
          alert("Email Required");
          return false;
       }else {
var re = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/";
return re.test(email);
}
       if ( phoneno == null || phoneno == "" ) {
          alert("Phone Required");
          return false;
       }

    }
    </script>
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, how can I check if the email format is correct like abc@example.com and also the phone # format is a 10 digit number and does not contain any letters or special characters ?

Comment: Use regex to validate email

Comment: @SubhasisKar There is no "name" attribute on apex:inputText.

Comment: @sfdcfox - you are correct. This can be handel by id attribute. answer edited. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: @vreddy Modified answer with correct email validation. Please accept my answer if it helps you

Comment: Thanks Subhasis and sfdcfox for helping me out. I tried the code and working fine for email : error is System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email: invalid email address: 1232#12323asda: [Email__c]
Error is in expression '{!save}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page survey: Class.Survey.save: line 103, column 1

Comment: can I get an alert on the same visualforce page?

Comment: Did you sending email any how??

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more detailed, when submitting the form ex: if the email is not a valid(123#123.com) then the users should have an alert or show error message that they have to enter a valid email. Until the email or phone is valid they cannot save the form.

Comment: I have update the regex pattern (var re = "/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/";) for email validation. please have a look and let me kno

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to upload jQuery as a static resource, or use a CDN link.

Next, you need to match the input elements to their "name" in order to use this module. At minimum, that means you'll need to specify some ID values, and then specify those names:

```
<apex:page controller="Survey" sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jQueryMin}" />
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jQueryValidateMin}" />

    <apex:form id="SurveyForm" >
        <apex:pageblock Title="Please fill the survey:" id="block1">
           <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" id="section1">
            <!-- removed for brevity -->
            <apex:inputText value="{!email}" label="Email" id="email" />

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $('surveyForm').validate({
                  rules: {
                       "{!$Component.SurveyForm.block1.section1.email}": {
                            required: true,
                            email: true,
                       }
                  }
             });
        });
</script>
</apex:page>
```